# How to call a static method on a generic constrained type

Tags: f#

given this example:

```
type Base() =
    static member Function() = ""

type Derived() =
    inherit Base()

let get<'T when 'T :> Base> segment =
    return ('T).Function()

let invoked = get<Derived>()
```

is there a way to call `Function` from `get`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SRTP could help you:

```
type Base() =
    static member Function() = ""

type Derived() =
    inherit Base()

let inline get< ^T 
        when ^T :> Base
        and  ^T : (static member Function: unit -> string)> =
     (^T : (static member Function: unit -> string) ())

let invoked1 = get<Derived>  //ok
let invoked2 = get<string>   //error: string not derived from Base
```